# How to assign values to vector using linear indexing in matlab?

Tags: matlab, indexing, assign

I have a vector with NaNs:

```
v1 = [NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN];
```

another vector with different values:

```
v2 = [1 4 6 8 9];
```

and linear index:

```
idx = [1 0 4 0 3];
```

I would like to assign values in v2 to v1 according to linear index so the result would be:

```
v1 = [1 NaN 8 NaN 6];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
v1(idx ~= 0) = v2(idx(idx ~= 0))
```

This takes

"The values in `v1` where `idx` is not equal to zero"

and assigns them the values in

"`v2`, at indexes `idx`, where `idx` is also not equal to zero"